# iOSビルドしたアップデートバージョンを申請できない

Tags: ios, build

iOSアプリのアップデート（ver.1.0.3)を行うために、Application Loaderで新しいバージョンのデータをiTunes connect上にビルドまではアクティビティ画面で無事にできているのを確認しているのですが、添付[image: スクショ]のようにApp Store画面のビルドの部分に1.0.3が出てきません。今の1.0.2を消すこともできなさそうで、ここからどうすればいいかわからなくなりました。どなたかご教示のほど、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問にあるスクリーンショットにも映ってますが、左側にある『＋ バージョンまたはプラットフォーム』を押して、新しいバージョンを作成する必要があります。

その後、新しいバージョンに対して変更点メッセージやビルドしたバイナリを選択できるようになります。